# Jenkins Pipeline Displays Password in Plaintex

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I am retrieving the username password from the `credentials` plugin.
The values are then saved as environmental variables. I am using the password in later stages of the pipeline, in `sh` block as an argument for `curl`.
At this point the password is displayed in plaintext in the build logs. Is there a way to avoid this? I assumed by using the `credentials` plugin the password will be masked.

```
pipeline {
 stages {
  stage ('One') {
  steps {
   withCredentials([userNamePassword(credentialsId: 'my_cred', userNameVariable: 'User_Name', passwordVariable: 'Password')]){
 env.User_Name = User_Name
 env.Password = Password
    }
  }
 }
 stage ('Two') {
   sh '''
    curl -v -u ${User_Name}:${Password} ...
    '''
  }
 }
}
```

Note: I am using the `curl` to upload a file to a remote host.

Comment: Use `curl` command inside `withCredentials` block instead of storing credentials and accessing them later. If you need to repeat `withCredentials` twice, just do it. Username and password retrieved from `withCredentials` gets masked as you expect inside the block.

Comment: Ok, Thanks. So there is no way around this? e.g, access the credentials outside the block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the `curl` inside the `withCredentials`block.

```
withCredentials([userNamePassword(credentialsId: 'my_cred', userNameVariable: 'User_Name', passwordVariable: 'Password')]){
   sh '''
    curl -v -u ${User_Name}:${Password} ...
      '''
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats true. The password will be displayed in plaintext.
The best way for your request, ist to use the  [HTTP Request Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/HTTP+Request+Plugin).
You can pass credentials in "Authorization" in the Header inestead of URL.

Comment: The `curl` is to upload a file. `httpRequest` does not provide this functionality.